# what is the nature of citta? nicca or anicca?

Tags: vipassana

I was thinking about tilakhana and cittanupassana. and this question occuerd to me.
that there is no mention in tipitaka about nicca/anicca nature of citta.
So something is very obvious that I am missing. and hence this question.

Comment: Citta is neither *nicca* nor *anicca* in the finality of everything. But beforehand, when one thinks they're being a jolly good Buddhist, learning all the terms, flexing their academic prowess, the notion of nicca & anicca define each other for the purpose of insight. Eventually, those insights become nonsense and cancel each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all due consideration, the right answer, according to the Teaching of the Enlightened One, is twofold:

1. Firstly, keeping the terms untranslated as they appear in the question, the epilogue for the chapter dealing with *Cittanupassana* from the *(Maha) Satipatthana Sutta* states, amongst other things:

*"samudayavayadhammanupassi va cittasmim viharati"*, thus describing the definition of *anicca*; or, if a translation is permitted, "he understands that **the state of mind has the nature of appearing-and-dissapearing**", thus describing the definition of impermanence

2. Secondly, with regard to *anicca* as one of the three marks of existence, namely *"sabbe sankhara anicca"*, or "**all conditioned things are impermanent**", *anicca* is equated to all that is conditioned, including the state of mind, or *citta*.

What can be said to be *Nicca*, or permanent, is only The Unconditioned, *"Asankhata"*, which while being manifested by the Enlightened One in a conditioned realm can be acknowledged as a completely liberated state of mind, or *"vimuttam cittam"*.

As an addendum, after the passing away of a completely enlightened being, the *"Parinibbana"* in the case of the *"Buddha"*, there is only The Unconditioned, so there are no more conditions, there is no more more mind thus no more state of mind.

Respectfully

P.S. The state of mind *citta*, progressing through the different stages, from a mind affected by lust *saragam cittam* to the highest stage of a mind that is liberated (from fetters, defilements and suffering) *vimuttam cittam* does not change the nature of the medium through which either un-attainment or the attainment of perfect freedom is manifested.

Just as when the Enlightened One spoke, he clearly spoke only the perfect truth, which is eternal *nicca*. It does not mean that the mouth of the *Buddha* was eternal, but only a means by which perfect truth, though unconditoned, was manifested in a conditioned realm.

Any human can manifest through either the body or the mind, either hindrances or qualities pertaining to enlightenment, which has an eternal and timeless nature. Still, manifesting qualities does not make either the body or the mind eternal or timeless. All it can do is point to and encourage towards attaining the unconditioned.

So in the last words of the truly worthy one, *vaya-dhamma sankhara, appamadena sampadetha*, **evanescence is the nature of created things; earnestly strive for the one true achievement**

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism Stack Exchange. Thank you for writing this excellent answer.

Comment: If you say (in abhidhamma style) citta as state of mind. then I wonder what it means by ceto-vimutti. what it means by pabhassaram cittam.  There must be something which is beyond just the state of mind. Isnt it? Or do you means ceto vimutti is freedom from citta?

Comment: @enRaiser Regarding *pabhassaram cittam*, please read "[Is luminous mind unconditioned and not impermanent?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25210/471)"

Comment: sadhu sadhu sadhu

Comment: This answer seems to say vimuttam cittam is permanent yet also says it ends with a Buddha passes away.

Comment: @Dhamma  Dhatu , Yes the answer is not complete, he has skipped my attempt to clarify on cettovimutti. And I think no one can answer. that when we say ceto vimutti, what is being freed from what?

Comment: @enRaiser, having assumed that the link kindly provided by ruben2020 had clarified the dilemma, it did not appear as necessary to further detail the answer. for now it has been added a post scriptum that should help with auxiliary concepts, bearing in mind that the original answer was written strictly with regard to the original question. in short, *citta* is *anicca* for any state of mind. and all-in-all, thank you for the opportunity of approaching the subject. respectfully

Comment: vimuttaṁ citta in MN 10 & DN 22 cannot mean liberated from fetters, defilements and suffering; otherwise it would be the last stage of practice.

Comment: a liberated state of mind means the consecutive arriving at each of the four stages of a noble person, *Ariya Puggala*, namely a stream-enterer, a once-returner, a non-returner and an enlightened being. for each of them, the mind is liberated progressively from the 10 fetters, *samyojana*, grouped in stages as they are discarded. it is said that even for a stream-enterer, the suffering that remains to be eradicated is infinitesimal compared to the one of aimlessly roaming the cycle of rebirth, *samsara*. so a mind that becomes purified, although in stages, is still said to be liberated

Answer (score 2):

> This body made up of the four primary elements is seen to last for a
> year, or for two, three, four, five, ten, twenty, thirty, forty,
> fifty, or a hundred years, or even longer.
>
> Dissatāyaṁ, bhikkhave, cātumahābhūtiko kāyo ekampi vassaṁ tiṭṭhamāno
> dvepi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno tīṇipi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno cattāripi vassāni
> tiṭṭhamāno pañcapi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno dasapi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno
> vīsatipi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno tiṁsampi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno cattārīsampi
> vassāni tiṭṭhamāno paññāsampi vassāni tiṭṭhamāno vassasatampi
> tiṭṭhamāno, bhiyyopi tiṭṭhamāno.
>
> But that which is called ‘**mind**’ or ‘intellect’ or ‘consciousness’
> arises as one thing and ceases as another all day and all night.
>
> Yañca kho etaṁ, bhikkhave, vuccati **cittaṁ** itipi, mano itipi,
> viññāṇaṁ itipi, taṁ rattiyā ca divasassa ca aññadeva uppajjati aññaṁ
> nirujjhati.
>
> SN 12.61

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the term 'citta' means something like 'attitude' or 'mental posture': the idea that the mind/body organizes itself for specific contexts. If we see someone (say) puff out their chest, raise their fists to fight, or turn and run, these are all physical postures that reflect an internal mental posture. One has adopted a mental posture of pride, of combat, or of flight, and that mental posture organizes the physical posture.

In that sense, citta precedes or is foundational to both self and no-self. It's merely the word for the general idea of having mental postures. It's a bit like the word 'sky', in the sense that 'sky' doesn't tell us whether it's bright or dark, warm or cold, rainy or dry. Sky is just *sky*, and all these conditions come out of it; citta is just *citta*, and all our mental conditions are formed in it. Then the question becomes whether our mental postures are organized or disorganized, harmonious or dissonant, attached or released.

If it helps clarify things, think of meditation as a mental posture — a citta — that we adopt to help reorganize and rehabilitate the jumble of discordant cities that our minds are prone to.

Comment: Where does *nicca* and *anicca* fit in all of that?

Comment: @Max: apologies, I thought that was clear. My bad...  *Nicca* refers to fixed attitudes or mental postures (oddly similar to the Freudian notion of [cathexis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathexis). A lot of mental activity involves invoking, defending, and switching among these mental postures. *Anicca* is the state where we loosen these mental postures so that they no longer dominate our minds (they are no longer 'fixed'). It too is a kind of mental posture, but not a fixed one (except in those practitioners who fall into the 'emptiness as form' trap).

Comment: Sorry - your reply was too intellectual - but thanks for trying! ;-)

Comment: @Max:   No worries.  